# DML inside a function call

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I have an old client software which has a connected oracle database for persistence. As interface the client software only allows the call of functions and procedures. I have nearly full access to the database, i.e., I can define functions and procedures. Because of the interface, only functions can return values and I cannot use the `OUT` parameter option of procedures.

Now I simply want to read a value from a table:

```
SELECT value FROM myTable WHERE id = 42;
```

And increase the value afterwards:

```
UPDATE myTable SET value = value + 1 WHERE id = 42;
```

I could use a function for the select statement and a procedure for the update and call both successively. The problem here is the non-existence of transactions on the client side. Thus, between select and update another thread could get wrong values.

So my question is, how can I use both calls in a transaction without using transactions...

**Tried Approaches:**

- Use anonymous PL/SQL Blocks -> the syntax is not supported by the client.
- Put both calls in a single function -> DML is not allowed in a select statement.
- `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` -> I heard it is a bad thing and should not be used.

Comment: `Functions` are intended to ***not*** have side effects.  If you want to alter the state of the database, then you need to use a `Procedure`.

Comment: If you want a simple `counter`, and there is nothing else going on in this scenario, you could consider `CREATE SEQUENCE`?

Comment: If I use the procedure (and can not use `OUT`), I need two database calls which is not thread save.

Comment: Then you need something like a `SEQUENCE` *(if you only have one counter, rather than a table full of counters)*, or someone needs to fix your software architecture.  You've listed all the things you can't use *(transactions, procedures, etc)* and so cut the balls off the database's ability to do what you want.  If you can't use what you should use, fix the problem preventing you from using the correct tools.

Comment: @MatBailie not sure if a squence would do the trick. I think, i cannot update it in a function as well? However, a trigger should work, increasing the value after the select?

Comment: There is no such thing as an `AFTER SELECT` trigger.

Comment: I cannot fix commerical software, which is not open source...

Comment: I'll paraphrase your situation : `I have software that means I can't use any of the intended database constructs to atomically query and amend data.  Is there some way that I can hack around and use the wrong database tools for the job, but it still be as robust as using the right tools?`  In short, you have an architectural issue, either the software isn't sufficient for your requirements (replace it) or it hasn't been configured / utilised in the correct manner for this use case.

Comment: This suggests that querying a sequence from inside a UDF works...  
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3905460?start=15&tstart=2

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks, now I understand where you want to make a call. BTW, how do you make this select statement, if your software can only call functions and procedures?

Comment: Simply in a function, like your deleted answer.

Comment: @Thanthla - Have you tried using a `SEQUENCE`?  The community.oracle link I provided implies that it may work as desired.

Comment: @Thanthla  In a function, like in my deleted answer, you can just make a select, and then make a separate update. If you select several rows, then update several rows. That's all. I can return it and elaborate, if you want.

Comment: @MatBailie I had a look at sequences and it should work for a single value. However I updated my question. The table has multiple lines, and thus I would need a squence for each tuple.

Comment: @Dmitry - You can do that in a procedure, but a function can't execute an `UPDATE` statement.  The OP wants to *atomically* read a value and then increment it, without using functions (because you can't do the UPDATE in a function), procedures (Because the OP's software can't read back the results), anonymous PL/SQL block (because the OP's software doesn't allow them) or transactions (Because the OP's software won't allow them)...

Answer (score 1):

You **can** do DML inside a function as demonstrated below, but I stress - take heed of the other comments.  Look at using a sequence (even multiple sequences), because doing DML inside a function is generally a bad idea, because the number of executions of a function call (if called from SQL) is not deterministic.  Also, there are scalability issues if used in a high volume.  And in a multi-user environment, you need to handle locking/serialization otherwise you'll multiple sessions getting the **same** integer value returned.

So...after all that, you **still** want to head this path :-(

```
SQL> create table t ( x int );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values (0);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  function f return int  is
  3    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  4    retval int;
  5  begin
  6    update t
  7    set x = x + 1
  8    returning x into retval;
  9    commit;
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> select f from dual;

         F
----------
         1

1 row selected.

SQL> select * from t;

         X
----------
         1

1 row selected.

SQL> select f from dual;

         F
----------
         2

1 row selected.

SQL> select * from t;

         X
----------
         2

1 row selected.

SQL> select f from dual;

         F
----------
         3

1 row selected.

SQL> select * from t;

         X
----------
         3

1 row selected.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew your proposed solution, and the problems with it. Thus, i will most likely drop the consistency and execute the function for reading and the procedure for updating. The chance of two threads executing this workflow interleaved is so low, that I may take the risk.

Comment: @Thanthla if the risk of that happening is low, it means that it still exists, so you need also to consider what are the consecuences of it happening, is not the same to say "if the counter fails no big deal is just an estimate for stadistics" to "if it fails the stock will be wrong and a product will be lost for a client".